# Nemiver doesn't find file /build/glibc-LK5gWL/glibc-2.23/stdlib/random.c

Tags: c++, debugging

When debugging code, when it comes to the rand () function, it asks where the file is. This file is not in libraries at all. What to do?

Comment: could you post your code or tell what IDE you are using.

Comment: @meysamimani It says right there in the title what software is being used, and the code is irrelevant.

Comment: I'm using geany.

Comment: Maybe problem with stdlib.h? Where I can download C++ libraries again?

Answer (score 2):

Your debugger is looking for source code to make itself more useful. In the case of compiled files that are part of glibc, that's not on your system. The path shown is just the path in the original build environment; that's irrelevant. It can use `random.c` if found elsewhere, but you need to tell it where to look.

The good news is that you can probably install a package to make this work. Which one depends on your operating system; you did not tell us what that is.

However I'd just hit "cancel". You don't need to debug the internals of glibc, unless you're actually trying to find bugs in glibc.

Comment: "You don't need to debug the internals of glibc, ever." - I disagree. I've had to debug glibc, openssl, qt, sfml, kernel (and more) internals on multiple occasions. Agree that you *usually* don't, but it happens...

Comment: @JesperJuhl I'm talking to the OP, so "you" == goodinsider, not Jesper Juhl :) Of course, if you are debugging a library, you want sources of that library; but if you are debugging your own Hello World program then you do not.

Comment: Yes, i press cancel and have another message: Сould not find file rand.c Maybe i download this file?

Comment: No, apply the same logic again.

Comment: Maybe problem with stdlib.h? Where I can download C++ libraries again?

Comment: You do not need to "download C++ libraries again". There is no need to give your debugger these source files. I'm a little surprised it's asking for them, but all you need to do is tell it "no".